# Kohana/защита скриптов при подключении

Tags: php, kohana

Натолкнулся на структуру.
Точкой вхождения является файл index.php ,где определяется

**index.php**

```
define('SYSPATH', realpath($system).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
require APPPATH.'bootstrap'.EXT;
```

Затем при каждом подключении файлов :
**bootstrap.php**

```
  <?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
```

-Это своего рода защита против того, чтобы мы не могли подключить файл **bootstrap.php** навпрямую?

-Если мы в файле  bootstrap.php подключаем файл **other.php** так мы должны таким же способом объявить переменную в файле **bootstrap.php** и проверить наличие в  **other.php**?

-какие есть еще пути аналогичной защиты(слышал что нельзя получить доступ к файлам в определенном размещении,подскажите)?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- да это такая защита от подключения скриптов
- подключаемый php файл должен иметь в 1й строке `<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');?>`
- ограничить доступ к файлам внутри папок можно ещё с помощью .htaccess.

Comment: За наводку  htaccess спасибо

Comment: а больше ничего и не понадобиться. Проверять константы - давняя практика. А сама по себе Kohana хорошо сделана в плане роутинга и просто так не отдаст системные файлы.